# Antonym for Nightmare

Tags: antonyms, history

Recently I was discussing nightmares vs. "good dreams" and realized there isn't a decent antonym (at least that I'm aware). My question is two-fold:

1. What is a good antonym for [Nightmare](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nightmare)?
2. Is there a reason English has such a spcefic term to describe bad dreams, or is this because the word dream already has a positive connotation?

Comment: It's a *sweet dream*.

Comment: Sometimes it's a *wet dream* . ;-)

Comment: Why should there be an antonym for _nightmare_? There's no antonym for _fall, sing, desk,_ or _embarrassed_. Most words don't have antonyms.

Comment: @Robusto sometimes those can be nightmares too...

Comment: Because there may not be an antonym for nightmare that doesn't mean there isn't, and if there is, why shouldn't someone know it?

Comment: @Zan700 just curious if anyone was familiar with why seemingly so much emphasis is placed on negative dreams vs. no corresponding word dedicated to good dreams.

Comment: @Asleepace. Nightmare derives from the Middle English word ‘mare’, which meant a ‘female evil spirit thought to lie upon and suffocate sleepers’. Conceptually, what would be the opposite of that? An erotic dream maybe. Not suffocation but release. I guess Robusto's wet dream is in the vicinity, but I can't imagine someone casually saying, "What a wet dream I had last night." or "Let me tell you about my wet dream." Perhaps propriety has blocked an antonym from developing. I have only nightmares.

Comment: @Zan700 I’m literally just causally gonna introduce this into the lexicon, “bro I had the wettest dream last night… it wasn’t the spirits that were coming” …